# Syncing multiple providers with one SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I want to sync com.android.contacts and com.android.calendar with one SyncAdapter. Is this possible?

If yes, how I have to edit following lines?

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:accountType="com.package.account"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:userVisible="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearently not:

"Each SyncAdapter spins up a SyncThread that is bound to the authority defined in sync-adapter.xml, and multiple authorities cannot be defined in this xml file..."

(kianatennyson)

[How to use one SyncAdapter-class for multiple authorities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510603/how-to-use-one-syncadapter-class-for-multiple-authorities)

Comment: This answer is wrong - while you can't tie a `SyncAdapter` to more than one authority, you can still access all exported `ContentProvider`s from `onPerformSync()` method...

Answer (score 1):

You can sync any `ContentProvider` from your `SyncAdapter`, as long as it is exported and allows for modification of the underlying data.

In order to accomplish this you DON'T need to specify the extra providers or authorities in your XML - just get a reference to `ContentResolver` inside `onPerformSync()` and use it to access `ContentProvider`s of interest.

For a bit more info, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30693866/2463035